# Misclassification error rate and accuracy

Tags: classification, matlab, pattern-recognition

[image: scatter plot]Below is a Matlab code for Bayes classifier which classifies arbitrary numbers into their classes.

```
 training = [3;5;17;19;24;27;31;38;45;48;52;56;66;69;73;78;84;88]; 
     target_class = [0;0;10;10;20;20;30;30;40;40;50;50;60;60;70;70;80;80];  

      test = [1:2:90]'; 
     class  = classify(test,training, target_class, 'diaglinear');  % Naive Bayes classifier 
 [test class]
```

(a) If someone could provide code snippets for calculating the Bayes error for misclassification and accuracy. I went through matlab's documentation regarding `[class,err]=classify(...)`. But, I am unable to follow it and work.

(b) Also, how to plot a scatter plot and histogram indicating the number of data points belonging to different classes? I tried out with `scatter(training(:),target_class(:))` but it gives something else!

(c) How to work with crossvalidate()? An example would really help.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(a)** To calculate misclassification error you need to know `test_class` as well. Then you can compare the output `class` variable with `test_class`.

```
misserr = sum(test_class~=class)./numel(test_class);
```

If you don't have the test classes the 2nd output argument `err` will give you an estimate for misclassification error applying generated model on the training set.

**(b)** If you have just 2 factors (columns) in the training data set you can just do

```
scatter(training(:,1),training(:,2),[],target_class)
```

Correspondingly, you can use SCATTER3 for 3 factors.

For more factors you can perform Principal Component Analysis with PRINCOMP and plot 2 or 3 first components.

*UPDATE*: I missed that you actually have only one factor. Your scatter statement can work pretty well. Why don't you like it? You can also color the points differently adding `target_class` as 4th argument. You can also exchange 1st and 2nd arguments for may be better representation.

**(c)** You can perform CV with [CROSSVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/crossval.html) and [CVPARTITION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/cvpartition.html) functions from Statistical Toolbox. See the documentation for useful examples.

Here is another SO question - [How to use a cross validation test with MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396639/how-to-use-a-cross-validation-test-with-matlab) with few additional options.

Comment: Hi.Thank you.(b) When I use scatter plot, I m getting several line plots instead of scatter points. Could you kindly provide the correct code for one column/factor data? (c) The objective of using cv for my case is to compare erformance of 2 or more classifiers,in this case bayes vs k-nn,PCA etc. So,how do I use CV I mean what parameters are to be fed in for comparative purpose. I find your examples easier to follow than Matlab's !

Comment: You shouldn't get lines with your scatter plot statement. I've tried `scatter(training, ones(size(training)), [], target_class)` and it worked well. Y axis and color depends on `target_class`.

Comment: You cannot apply all these classifiers with CLASSIFY. It has only 4 types of classifiers. I believe you can do it with cross validation. See for instance Example 2 in the doc for CROSSVAL. You will have to provide different predicting functions (other than classify). It will return missclassification rate you can use to compare different functions.

Comment: I know other packages that can compare different classification methods, like CMA in R, weka (or wekamine), etc.

Comment: Instead of using CROSSVAL,the code which you provided misserr = sum(test_class~=class)./numel(test_class); would equally serve the purpose of giving a misclassification?I have uploaded the image of scatter plot...is it correct since it does not give any information (a small sample training size of 20).Also,could you provide a link where I can get a simple implementation of k-nn?

Comment: If your training and test samples are actually from the same data set, you'd better to do CV and get mean/median MCR to avoid any random effects. If those data are from different datasets and you want to use test data for validation purpose, you may have an issue. Basically one shouldn't find a best classifier (or optimize some classification parameters) using test dataset. Then you will need another validation dataset.

Comment: For k-nn classification you can use [knnclassify](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html).

Comment: Thank you once again.My test data set is different from the training set. So,what if I just want to use scatter plot individually for the training set and another scatter plot for test set so that I get a visual interpretaion just like histograms telling how many samples belong to a particular class. I tried [T,C]=hist(training_data,class) but does not work.As you must have guessed I have limited skills since I am a biologist.

Comment: You can try confusion matrix: `[cm, cm_lbl] = confusionmat(test_class,class);`
`

Comment: Please don't make this discussion to long. Why not to ask additional questions if you still have problems?